# Average deviation of uniform law

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I compute the average deviation over a datasets of $n$ data in $[0,1]$ as $d=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left|x_{i}-\mu\right|$ where $\mu$ is the usual average defined as $\mu=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}$.

I know that my $x_i$ follow a uniform law $U(0,1)$. The expected value of such a random variable is known and equals 1/2.

But I cannot find the expression of $d$ in that case and cannot figure out a way to demonstrate it either.

Does anyone knows the answer or could give a demo ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{E}$
Let $X$ have the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$. Then the expectation is
$\mu=1/2$ as you say. Calculate the mean deviation as
$$ 
  \E |X-\mu |  = \int_0^1 |x-0.5| \, dx = \int_0^{0.5} -(x-0.5)\, dx + \int_{0.5}^1  (x-0.5) \, dx = 1/4 =0.25
$$
Then you can just use linearity of expectation to get $\E d = n/4$.

Comment: This can also be seen directly this way: Clearly $|X-\mu|$ have the uniform distribution on $[0, 1/2]$, so the expectation must be $0.25$.